# Child Linear Layout is not using the full parent's height

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout with another LinearLayout as its child.
The child LinearLayout is supposed to be half of the parents size, but it's only like 40% the parent's height.

This is how I'm adding the child LinearLayout:

```
AddView (childLinearLayout, new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MatchParent, 0, .5f));
```

The parent LinearLayout has vertical orientation and a weight sum of 1.

Comment: I read something about fill view port, but i'm not sure if that is the answer or how to assign it in code.

Comment: are you using scrollview

Comment: No. Both are linear layouts. The outer linear layout is contained in a relative layout, but I don't think it matters

Comment: Have you tried setting the weightsum of the parent? Also, try not zeroing the height. Some people have said that it doesn't behave like xml in that regard.

Comment: yes, the weightsum is set to 1. If i don't set the height to zero, the layout weight is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code helps you:

```
       layout.addView(childLayout,new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent, .5f));
```